# Good Database design/normalisation

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I was assigned a task, with which I am not sure how to approach it:

I have to build a Messaging-System which supports multiple devices and it should be as efficient as possible.
Users can have up to 10 devices, which all need to receive a Message when the User receives it.

I have two Ideas:

```
Table Messages:
- ID (PK)
- SenderID
- ReceiverID
- Data

Table PendingTransmissions:
- MessageID (FK (PK of above table))
- DeviceID (FK)
```

The Problem here is that every time a message is sent, one entry per device is created and results in big overhead.

```
Table Messages:
- ID (PK)
- SenderID
- ReceiverID
- Data
- ReceivedDevice1
- ReceivedDevice2
- ReceivedDevice3
- ReceivedDevice4
- ReceivedDevice5
- ReceivedDevice6
- ReceivedDevice7
- ReceivedDevice8
- ReceivedDevice9
- ReceivedDevice10
```

The problem here is obviously the redundance of Devices, but the overhead would be lower.

What is the better solution or is there something I have missed completely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you consider to be "big overhead"?  Are you inserting each row into PendingTransmissions one at a time?

Comment: Put the registered receivers devices in a seperate table. Then when sending a message look at that table for the user receiving the message and send to all devices registered

Comment: On a side note, "efficient as possible" (presumably in terms of speed) is almost never really a requirement.  You'll never be done because there's always some possibility you can make it faster.  You need to figure out what is good enough performance and then design to that.

Comment: Big overhead in a table with two indexed ids? I don't see a big overhead. Solution 2 is way worse. Go with #1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against the 2nd approach for (at least) two reasons:

- Today, one User can have 10 devices. If that number changes to, say, 20 in future, that means changes in many layers in your application: database, application entity classes, DAO etc.
- In future, you might want to add functionality for groups. It'll be cumbersome to extend this design for that.

In 1st approach, if you are concerned about your `PendingTransmissions` becoming too big in size, you can take care of it like this:

- Add two columns: `isDelivered` and `deliveredTimestamp`. You can then periodically archive all rows which are both delivered and older than, say, 1 month.

Comment: Plus the 2nd idea violates the basic data normalization tenet of first normal form. http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Answer (score 3):

The first approach is totally valid and it should be the way to go. The maintainability of the second approach is a horror and on a later time when some code is added the code won't be very readable (i had to maintain multiple DBs already that where designed this way).

Comment: I've had the same experience and agree wholeheartedly.